# How to configure to run the springboot tests against an already up and running service on a different location

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

I have to configure my integration tests to run against the service that is up and running in a different location.Currently my tests are for localhost and they are starting the service by the below annotations defined in a parent class :

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes =ServiceApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8084")
```

In the child classes this is how I have configured my tests to get the port and endpoint to run the tests :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RunningIntegrationIT extends BaseTestService {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;
    private String uri = "/service/firstName";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
    }
```

Now if I have to make the tests run against the service already running on a different ipaddress and port then how to configure that setting. Seems like if I use the @IntegrationTest it starts the spring-boot tomcat by default.

Also I have read to use the @ActiveProfile but can someone give me details on how to use this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

`local.server.port` has `local` in it. You can't just use that to refer to a different process that you expect to run. Your tests becomes pure client test so maybe they should not even use spring boot at all.

What auto-configuration piece are you using in your test? Maybe using Spring Boot there doesn't bring much?

I understand you may want to share the same test suite between a service that Spring Boot would start and a remote instance. That's fine: just write your test in an abstract class and have two implementations. The full remote one may not even use Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane can you explain with an example?

Comment: explain what exactly?

Comment: so I was able to achieve what I wanted by creating a property file and reading from that in a base class. I removed the local.server.port as it was just starting the service on local and set the port in @Before